# amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib takes 2 messages at start

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-sqs, spring-jms

I am reading SQS queue with `amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib` and `@JmsListener`.

My configuration is the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class JmsConfig {
  @Bean
  public SQSConnectionFactory connectionFactory(AmazonSQS amazonSQS) {
    return new SQSConnectionFactory(new ProviderConfiguration(), amazonSQS);
  }

  @Bean
  public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(SQSConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    return new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory);
  }

  @Bean
  public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory(SQSConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                                        MessageConverter converter) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setMaxMessagesPerTask(1);
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    factory.setDestinationResolver(new DynamicDestinationResolver());
    factory.setConcurrency("1");
    factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    factory.setMessageConverter(converter);
    return factory;
  }
}
```

Here I mean that I want to process messages strictly one-by-one.

I'm working on the use-case when my queue contains several messages and the application starts.

When the application connects to the queue it takes 2 messages at the very beginning. Afterwards it consumes one-by-one but the number of messages In Flight is always 2.

(I tried to debug and looks like SQSMessageConsumerPrefetch misses its first reading)

Is it my bad configuration or is it a real issue?
Thank you